# onchange event is fired on button click and not on dynamically created select element

Tags: javascript, function, events, select, dynamic

I use this on dynamically created select but the function is not being called

```
select.onchange = function(select) {getdetails();};
```

I use this way, and the function is being called from a static button's click (I also try not appending the select to its DIV container)

```
select.addEventListener('change', getdetails());
```

Please help thanks.

Comment: In the first, example, you can't pass in `select` like that. The function will accept the `event` object. In the second example, you should remove the `()`. That is making whatever `getdetails()` returns the callback, not `getdetails` itself.

Comment: @m59 you should post this as answer to the question.

Comment: my function have paramters, I remove it for simplicity, its being called on a button click not on the select onchange event select.addEventListener('change', showRENI(reni_string,this,i));

Comment: @joeytje50 heh, good idea =D Done!

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code doing what you described: [**Live demo here (click).**](http://jsbin.com/aTUlEWUW/1/edit)

```
var select = document.createElement('select');
var option = document.createElement('option');
option.textContent = 'Option 1';
var option2 = document.createElement('option');
option2.textContent = 'Option 2';
select.appendChild(option);
select.appendChild(option2);

select.addEventListener('change', getDetails);
document.body.appendChild(select);

function getDetails(e) {
  console.log('Running!');
}
```

**Update according to your comments - passing parameters to event listener:**

```
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  getDetails(some, params, here);
});
```

You can't call the function directly and pass in parameter like you were trying to do here `select.addEventListener('change', getdetails());`. Consider this example:

```
function getdetails() {
  return 'a';
}
select.addEventListener('change', getdetails());
```

in the above code, the returned value of `getdetails()` is passed as the callback, so this is the same result: `select.addEventListener('change', 'a');` See why your function wasn't called?

Also, this method is outdated:

```
select.onchange = function(event) {
  console.log(event);
};
```

Use `addEventListener` instead. If you do use it, note that it accepts the "event" object. You can't just pass in whatever you want. If you needed to pass something in, then call another function there and pass in what you need, like this:

```
select.onchange = function(event) {
  getdetails(pass, the, params, you, need)
};
```

### Update to be sure I'm clear:

Don't call the function your trying to pass as a callback!!!!

You're doing this (wrong);

```
elem.addEventListener('change', myFunc());
```

You need to do this (right):

```
elem.addEventListener('change', myFunc);
```

Now, for dealing with passing parameters to `myFunc` you can do this:

```
elem.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  myFunc(some, parameters, here);
});
```

**OR:**

```
elem.addEventListener('change', someFunc);

function someFunc(e) {
  myFunc(some, parameters, here);
}
```

Comment: Im using the code on Adobe AIR, my problem is the function is being called when I clicked the button to generate the select.

Comment: @user2533639 I just explained that in my updated post. That's because you're calling the function rather than passing it as a callback.

Comment: How then should I attach the function to the select element?

Comment: Im sorry, its my first time to post. I already use your suggestion, but its not calling the function. It use to work when select was not created using createElement and using jquery's $(document).on('change',elementid,getdetails(p1,p2,p3)). Thank you very mmuch for your time.

Comment: @user2533639 like I said, I've answered as good as it can be answered. If you need any additional help, you need to add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: @user2533639 Have you figured this out, now? I would appreciate if you click the accept checkmark on my answer as it is very thorough. This will also reward you some reputation points.